# Self-hosted, open-source web client for own mail and calendar servers

Tags: mail, client, caldav

I have own virtual private server and I'm looking for self-hosted, open-source web software (some client) with GUI to manage mail accounts and calendars.

Can you recommend me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Nextcloud, and host it on a shared hosting service (Dreamhost). I don't use it for email, but there is a mail integration you can install: 
https://github.com/nextcloud/mail

Comment: oh, it looks great, I think that it's what I need. Do you have access to the server or do you only use pre-installed software on shared hosting service?

Comment: I installed it myself on my Dreamhost account. Happy to detail my settings if you need.